# Not able to insert data into SQL Server through Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, insert

Compiler is not showing any error. I wonder whats the problem in it.

And yes its also not showing message "Inserted !!"

This is my first data inserting in Winforms. Yes I am new.

Code:

```
public partial class Phone : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=phonemo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********");

    public Phone()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("This will Clear Text", "New", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            //do something else
        }

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Clear();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        textBox1.Focus();

        con.Open();
        String query = "INSERT INTO phonemoo (Fname,Sname,Mobile,Email,Catagory) VALUES ('"+ textBox1.Text +"','"+ textBox2.Text +"','"+ textBox3.Text +"','"+ textBox4.Text +"','"+ comboBox1.Text + "')";

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);
        sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Inserted !!");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you clear all controls and then save their (empty) values?

Comment: clear what?? Didn't understood that .. would you explain it more

Comment: Stop **everything**, and don't write a single line of code until you've read all there is to know about SQL injection. Also, don't connect as `sa`. Then, you open the connection once and close it each time you click the button - just open it every time you click the button instead. Lastly, just use a debugger to see what's going on

Comment: @BurhanAhmed, In your code you have: `textBox1.Text = "";textBox2.Clear(); ...`and then you store their values (in query)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yes i know little bit about sql injection..but right now i only need to insert my data into database :P

Comment: @RomaDoskoch so what should i do ?? remove this query or there is something else i should do

Comment: @BurhanAhmed, if you remove your query you won't insert data. Try to clear you controls after your call `MessageBox.Show()`. Also, if there are some exception provide it please.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is selected in your combobox - **comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1**.  But you try to insert the combobox text into the Category field.  I'd look there for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have cleared textbox value before insert into database.
Change your code---

```
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=phonemo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********");

    public Phone()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Phone_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("This will Clear Text", "New", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            //do something else
        }




        con.Open();
        String query = "INSERT INTO phonemoo (Fname,Sname,Mobile,Email,Catagory) VALUES ('"+ textBox1.Text +"','"+ textBox2.Text +"','"+ textBox3.Text +"','"+ textBox4.Text +"','"+ comboBox1.Text + "')";

     SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query,con);
     sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

     con.Close();

        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Clear();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        textBox1.Focus();

     MessageBox.Show("Inserted !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: what changes should i made ??